# how to align one image to another after sliding with a finger?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, uigesturerecognizer

I have an `activity.xml`

The user can move these boxes (buttons) with his finger to the right and to the left.

However the white small arrow doesn't reach to the middle of the box

(sometimes too right, sometimes too left)

[image]

I have tried to add/remove margine to its left.

But it didn't help.

[image]

Where should I look around?

```
 <com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/searchButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/engines_bg"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="25dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/leftMargin"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView>
```

Maybe the fix should be in the code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    Log.d("w","ontouchevent");      
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("WAZE","action up");
        Integer min_dist=null;
        SearchEngine min_se=null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<Object, SearchEngine> engines=(Map<Object, SearchEngine>)getTag(R.id.searchEngines);
        Iterator<SearchEngine> i=engines.values().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            SearchEngine tmp_se=(SearchEngine)i.next();
            int tmp_dist=Math.abs(tmp_se.getButton().getButtonXPosition()-getScrollX()-getWidth()/2);
            if (min_dist==null || tmp_dist<min_dist) {
                min_dist=tmp_dist;
                min_se=tmp_se;
            }
        }
        ((SearchActivity)getTag(R.id.searchActivity)).setActiveEngine(min_se);
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: I really can't understand your question.

Comment: sorry, was missing pictures

Comment: So as i understand you want the triangle to be centered to white box?

Comment: yes, but not only at the beginning. But also when I swap the finger and the buttons move left\right

Comment: show us some code how are you doing it.

Comment: please add a picture how it's look after the swipe action ?

Comment: @TomerMor I want to delete current question. Can you please refer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654479/how-to-make-scrollto-stop-where-i-intend

Comment: what is the id of that arrow in your xml?

Comment: I've made a little sample related to your attempt at centering the content buttons(and I assume you want some snap effect when the arrow is not on the center of either of those buttons after a user scroll). It's something basic, you can find it here: https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/view/SnappingScroll.java

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

With this, your arrow is aligned with your Parent (the button). I searched on android developpers and I found a xml attribute which could be very usefull for you :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

In Android Developper, here is the decription :

> If true, centers this child horizontally within its parent.

Hope it'll work; I'm new on StackOverflow, maybe my answer isn't well-formatted.

Comment: nope. It made the bottom bar to be at the top of my screen. btw, I want the triangle be center after the user swap the buttons with his finger, not on the static initial position

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, take a look at the **pointing arrow** location - It's simply **not located in the horizontal middle** of the screen. you are actually doing everything right in the scroll view.

Take a real screenshot from the application to test it out.

Comment: you're right, that's why I have posted this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702609/why-is-my-9png-photo-si-starched-to-the-right?noredirect=1#comment25866184_17702609

and yet I'm not sure why in the editor it's in the middle whereas in the application itslef it's  not