# why is my 9png photo si starched to the right?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, user-interface

I have this image(`@drawable/engines_bg`), as my Horizontal Scroll view:
[image]

you can see the triangle is in the exact middle.

However, when I run my Activity, the triangle is closed to the left:

(if you measure with a roller)

[image]

how can it be?

I have checked and there is no re-positioning in the code.

here is my xml:

```
<com.w.view.title.TitleBar
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/searchResultsList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchButtonBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/searchButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/engines_bg"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftMargin"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
            android:onClick="engineClicked" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
            android:onClick="engineClicked" />

      <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rightMargin"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchProgressPopup"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_transparent_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <com.w.view.map.ProgressAnimation
        android:id="@+id/searchProgressAnimation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchProgressText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_shadow" />
```

update:

I have tried @Brian's solution, but it's all mixed up:

```
<com.w.view.title.TitleBar
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/searchResultsList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchButtonBarWrapper"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchButtonBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/engines_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/searchButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="25dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/leftMargin"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:onClick="engineClicked" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/rightMargin"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.w.navigate.SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchProgressPopup"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_transparent_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <com.w.view.map.ProgressAnimation
        android:id="@+id/searchProgressAnimation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchProgressText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar_shadow" />
```

The result:

[image]

*Uapdte2: Tried Luksprog's 9.png*

I had two problems:

1) the 1 pixel dots are visible

2) the arrow is to strached

3) I sae the original 9.png in two folders. How can I know which one my device relates to?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the 9-patch image?

Comment: can you post 9-patch image with indication of borders

Comment: One thing you could try: wrap the horizontal scrollview in another ViewGroup container, set that container's width to `match_parent`, and apply the background to that container rather than the scrollview. There may be some strange issues around positioning the background on the scrollview because of the variable width calculations.

Comment: the first image is the 9-patch. you can see small baclk dots.

Comment: @njzk2 yes. that's @drawable/engines_bg

Comment: I'd say the SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView should be match_parent in width.

Comment: @njzk2 tried that, didn't help

Comment: @Brian which `ViewGroup container` would you suggest? a linear layout?

Comment: @EladBenda Yes, I'd go with a `LinearLayout`. There are simpler containers, but `LinearLayout` always seems to behave well.

Comment: @Brian I have tried your solution, but it's all messed up now

Comment: Don't use the `gravity` property on `SearchButtonsBarHorizontalScrollView` and the `layout_gravity` on the child `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Luksprog relating to which xml? the first or the second one?

Comment: In whatever one you use, those properties tend to cause problems when used with a ScrollView(and they don't make any sense using anyway). Related to your drawable, make sure that the extension points used vertically are **exactly the same** and that you also have versions for every screen density.

Comment: @EladBenda Does it help at all to set the ScrollView's layout_width to wrap_content? I believe that's the recommended setting for horizontal ScrollViews, although I'm not sure if it will solve your issue.

Comment: @Luksprog How do I check `make sure that the extension points used vertically are exactly the same`. I have got the image, jsut to check the distance between every black dot to the border?

Comment: @Brian I have tried this too. Didn't help

Comment: The black point on the x axis should have the same size(sorry about the vertical stuff I said). Anyway I was curios about the behavior and I used your nine patch. I would say the behavior you see it's due to the nine patch being bigger than the screen. Use this drawable(much smaller) and see how it goes http://imgur.com/YNWRImd

Comment: but then I'll always have dismatch with wider or smaller screen. no? How can I fix it for all screens?

Comment: i think we're in the right track. I have tried you png. please see my updated question

Comment: You were right. I have fixed that but have ruined the transparancy. Can you answer the question and I'll mark yours as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nine patch image is too big to be handled by the `ScrollView` so the arrow doesn't get in the middle where you'd want it. So make the nine patch image smaller in width(that would be one of the advantages of nine patches vs regular images) by simply taking out two equal chunks from the left and right of the arrow and also adding the stretch points(which should be equal so the image gets stretched proportionally).

Here's my attempt(which should be saved as `the_image_etc.9.png`):

[image]

If you miss transparency somewhere it may be due to me saving that wrong but the general approach of obtaining the image is above.

> I save the original 9.png in two folders. How can I know which one my
>   device relates to?

When using a nine patch you need to have a version for each of the density drawable folders(so the image itself doesn't get resized using the image from another density folder), you don't need versions for different sizes of the screens(that's what is great about nine patches, they take out the size issue by extending themselves).